# Clarinets in the Rite of Spring

Tags: orchestration, clarinet, bass-clarinet

I am studying a miniature score of Stravinsky's The Rite of Spring (Dover Miniature Scores).  For the clarinets, I see this in the instrumentation page:

```
Clarinetto piccolo (D, Es)

3 Clarinetti (B, A) (Cl. II = Cl. b. II)

Clarinetto basso (B) (= Cl. IV)
```

This appears to be Italian but with German notes.

Alongside, there is the English:

```
Small Clarinet (D, E♭)

3 Clarinets (B♭, A)(Cl. II = Bass Cl.II)

Bass Clarinet (B♭) (= Cl. IV)
```

So, we need 5 players but the number of instruments is less clear.  Using some invented names to make discussion easier.

Alice plays the small clarinets.  She needs a D and an E♭.

Bob plays only a standard clarinet.  He needs an A and B♭.

Carol mostly plays a standard clarinet but may be required to play a second bass.  She needs an A, B♭ and a bass.

David, like Bob, plays only a standard clarinet.  He needs an A and B♭.

Elizabeth mostly pass the bass but may be called on to play 4th regular clarinet.  She needs a bass and one or both of an A and B♭.

It is Elizabeth's role that is least clear to me.

If I am correct, between them, there are:

1 D

1 E♭

3 or 4 A

3 or 4 B♭

2 bass

So, 10, 11, or 12 depending on the interpretation of Elizabeth's role.

I will examine the score in more detail later to try to find more clues.

Note that this question was originally combined with one on the bass clarinet notation.  I have split them.

Comment: I just scanned a score (in a PDF on my phone, so not very carefully) and I think I saw that there is inconsistency about bass clarinet II, which is sometimes played by Cl. II and sometimes by Cl. III.  It also looks like there are never three A clarinets.  It does indeed seem that (as asserted in a comment on the related question) bass clarinet I never plays anything else.  So it could be that 9 instruments are possible. Thanks for picking up on my abortive attempt at naming the players :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instrumentation page in the Dover score is incorrect.  If you closely look at the score and the [parts](https://imslp.org/wiki/The_Rite_of_Spring_(Stravinsky,_Igor)) you will see:

- Clarinet III plays Bass Clarinet II (and never plays A clarinet).
- Bass Clarinet I plays only bass (there is no Clarinet IV).

So a total of nine instruments are needed.

- E♭, D
- I. B♭, A
- II. B♭, A
- III. B♭, bass
- bass

Note: since D clarinets are quite rare, the player will very often transpose those parts for E-flat clarinet.

Comment: Thanks.  That explains some puzzles e.g. the odd reference to Cl. IV.  However, it suggests that the bass players need an A as well as a B♭ instrument.  I have heard of but not seen these.

Comment: @badjohn Bass clarinets in A have been called for sometimes, but not in this piece

Comment: But that link says: "Clarinet 1, 2, 3/Bass Clarinet 2 (A, Bb),
Piccolo Clarinet (D, E♭), Bass Clarinet 1 (A, B♭)" which seems to be calling for A and B♭ bass clarinets.

Comment: @badjohn The link is wrong, there is **no** bass clarinet in A in this piece. I just looked through the parts: Clarinet III never plays A clarinet, so I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks again.  I will probably listen again and follow only the clarinets in the score but I expect that you are right.

Comment: I have just scanned the score and this is correct.  There are frequently 5 clarinet parts but never more so 5 players.  One is dedicated to the D / E♭.  Two need A and B♭.  One needs a B♭ and a B♭ bass.  One needs only a B♭ bass.  There are never 3As at once but there are sometimes 2.